# What is the Read Tag command for NFC Tag ISO 14443-3A type

Tags: ios, nfc

I need a Read Tag command for NFC Tag ISO 14443-3A type.
For example - we can get UID using FFCA0000.

I am using FEITIAN reader BR500 and their SDK.

http://www.pcscreader.com/docs/ios.html
https://github.com/FeitianSmartcardReader/FEITIAN_MOBILE_READERS

I can use NFC Tools iOS app to read and write tags. But when using FEITIAN sdk I need to send APDU command to read the tags written.

So is there any command to read tags? Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APDU command to read data is

```
CLASS INS P1 P2 LC  
FF    B0  00 XX YY

 where XX is block number, YY is the data that will be read from card, the data size is 0-16
```

For example:
ffb0000410  will read block 04 and 16 bytes.
ffb0000510  will read block 05 and 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

An ISO 14443-3A type NFC Tag can only provide the UID (and a few other parameters that are some times used to identify card types) as part of the multiple card anti collision handling process.

NFC cards use various different higher level protocols to transfer their actual data content, therefore there is no ISO 14443-3A command to read a Tag.

ISO 14443-3A is more RFID than NFC (there is a overlap)

The below picture is an overview of the different NFC protocols used

[image: NFC Protocols]

Comment: I have edited and added more info in the question

Comment: Still not enough data on the Tag to tell which higher level protocol the Tag could use to read data from the Tag, so really need Tag Make and Model (NFC Tools should more details of the higher level protocols the Tag supports / the Tag make+model). Combining that info with Card reader info you should tell you how to communicate with the Tag at the higher level protocols needed.