# Relation between APDU and higher level NFC protocols (such as ISO 14443-3A)?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I started reading into the topic of NFC/Smartcard-Communication and I found many different standards and commands depending on the Tag type (for example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67750018/6139079))

I also came across the APDU-commands which seem universal to the communication of nfc/smartcards?

Does this mean, that these higher level protocols are all based on apdu and can be translated?

As an example, I found **NFC 14443-A** commands implemented with the `android.nfc.tech.NfcA` library, such as:

| Action | Byte |
| --- | --- |
| Read | 0x30 |
| Write | 0xA2 |

And **APDU** commands like these:

| Action | CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | LC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| READ BINARY | 0xFF | 0xB0 | ... | ... | ... |
| UPDATE BINARY | 0xFF | 0xD6 | ... | ... | ... |
| GET DATA | 0xFF | 0xCA | ... | ... | ... |
| MIFARE CLASSIC READ | 0xFF | 0xF3 | ... | ... | ... |
| MIFARE CLASSIC WRITE | 0xFF | 0xF4 | ... | ... | ... |

The commands seem to be completely different.

It would also help alot, if someone could point to good documentation on the topic

---

**Documentation I have found so far:**

The Android documentation on nfca ([Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA))

APDU description on wikipedia [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit)
(The [german](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Protocol_Data_Unit) version contains some return codes)

APDU commands (by a card-reader manufacturer) [Link](https://files.springcard.com/pub/pmd841p-fa.pdf)

Comment: In general, a "smart card" is just a card that is based on a general purpose CPU. You can basically program it to do anything. ISO 7816-4 is probably the most used standard, but about no card *fully* supports it and some other smart card standards only support a small portion of it. E.g. Java Card only supports the APDU *structure* - if you want it to support files you'll have to program that yourself.

Comment: Some of this APDUs come from the [PC/SC specification](http://pcscworkgroup.com/Download/Specifications/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf) for contactless (3.1.3 and 3.2.2). Another document to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it a bit wrong, 14443-3A is lower level that APDU's which come from the higher level ISO 7816 protocol.

But the Byte's ( `0x30` and `0xA2`) you reference as NFC 14443-A are not from NFC 14443-A but look like vendor specific Mifare Ultralight protocol commands which are again above NFC 14443-A

There is also a complication and probably the reason you are confused with APDU's you listed according to the [ISO 7816 spec](https://github.com/dongri/emv-qrcode-doc/blob/master/ISO%20IEC%207816-4.pdf), all the APDU's you specified have a CLA of `0xFF` are "invalid".

The reason for this is that a USB readers also use ISO 7816 for the host CPU to talk the NFC chip to work mainly with NFC Type 4 Tags, because `0xFF` are invalid for ISO 7816 the reader uses them for other non ISO 7816 things the NFC chip can do, e.g. communicate to non standard Mifare classic commands, turn on/off the LED's on the USB reader, etc

So really CLA's of `0xFF` are just a way to wrap other commands.

Or in a rough pictorial form

[image]

I would read as much of the Standard specification documents shown in the Stackoverflow you linked to and I wrote.  There are a lot of specifications used/part used

I know that they are really pay for items but they are out there on the Internet.

e.g.

http://www.emutag.com/iso/14443-3.pdf

http://www.emutag.com/iso/14443-4.pdf

For the higher level NDEF stuff https://github.com/haldean/ndef/tree/master/docs

For the Various NFC Forum Standards

[Google Index](https://www.google.com/search?q=NFCForum-TS-Type%20site:apps4android.org) of the 4 Types